# yum upgrade gives: ... conflicts between attempted installs of [32-bit package] and [64-bit package]

Tags: redhat, centos7, yum, upgrade

Our Red Hat 7.6 machines have 64-bit and 32-bit libraries installed.
I am scripting an update for all of our machines to run with our post-install scripts to upgrade all of the installed packages.
`yum -y upgrade`  return many errors like this:
`printers.pyc conflicts between libstdc++.i686 and libstdc++.x86_64`
I have many of these errors on each machine. Each machine is different. I cannot just uninstall 32-bit the conflicting packages, upgrade and then re-install the 32-bit packages. There are just too many.

I've tried:
`yum upgrade -x '*.i686'` to no avail.

How can I overcome these errors *en masse*?

**UPDATE:**
Here is one of the error messages.

> Transaction check error:
>   file */path/to/file/*printers.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7_6.2.i686 and libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7_6.2.x86_64

Notice that I have the same version available for both 32 and 64 bit packages.
`yum provides printers.pyc`
Returns both the 32 and 64 bit packages as installed:

> libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 and libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64

Each machine is different. I cannot just uninstall the 32-bit libstdc++ and "call it good." Another machine will have different conflicts.

I need to script this. I have to deal with the entire set of installed RPMs, and just uninstall a few onsie-twosie packages.

Is it possible to upgrade ONLY the 64-bit packages first, the upgrade the 32s? Will that help?

Comment: Do you really need the 32-bit packages installed? Usually the best bet is to just remove them.

Comment: Yes. I need the 32-bit code. Removed it on another machine and our custom code blew up. Haven't tracked it down yet, so we have to keep the 32-bit stuff.

Comment: Are you actually getting packages directly from RHEL? Or do you have private repos on Satellite or something? This also happens when your private repo is out of sync with the upstream repo, or is missing packages from it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am on a closed network. I have a static copy of the repos on my network. So, I cannot be "out of sync with the upstream" because there is no upstream.

Comment: Yes, you can be out of sync, and most likely you are. Of course there is an upstream; it's RHEL. Where else could you have gotten the offline packages?

Comment: Out of sync with what? I have no internet connection. The only repos I have are static. If I need to upgrade my Repos, it is a request to the internet team to download the repos from RHEL, burn them to a DVD and then we copy it to a new repo on our repository server. Unless I NEED that repository, my servers will not point to it.

Comment: Out of sync with the repos from RHEL, of course. For instance, if the internet team did not download all the packages which were in the repo, or the packages in the repo changed while they were being downloaded. I'm very suspicious now, as AFAIK all the packages won't fit on a single DVD anyway.

Comment: Except, my repo has been in place for sometime. All of the packages that I need exist in the repo. We are decoupled with RHEL. It does not matter what they are currently using. The only thing my server can see id my repo. Nothing else. If I had a package that had a dependency on a package that I don't have, I would get a dependency failure. The error that I am getting says, basically, "this 1 file can come from the 32-bit or the 64 bit repo, and I don't know which one to use -- help me Obi Wan!"

Comment: OK, I think I see where you're at. The packages aren't missing, but conflicting. That probably isn't a problem with the repo, then. But this still shouldn't be happening, and I can't reproduce it. Does the system at installation time have any version of libstdc++ installed? Which ones? If updating is part of bringing the server up, why not just have the updates installed as part of the OS installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was ugly. I had to list all the packages with conflicts. Remove the 32-bit packages by forcing and no dependencies.
Next, I had to upgrade all of the 64-bit packages.
After that, I could re-install the 32-bit packages.

Somehow, our kickstart process was messing this up. When we upgraded to the next version of Red Hat, we used a different kickstart image & post-install scripts. This cured the problem going forward.

We still don't know how it got messed up in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`yum` wants thos library versions to match. `libstdc++` for example will have to be installed with the exact same version number for both 32 and 64 bit.

Your proposition to remove the 32bit versions and then re-install them won't work; `yum` won't allow you to reinstall those 32bit versions if they don't match the exact same version number.

What happens is that probably there is an update available for `libstdc++.x86_64` and not for `libstdc++.i686` in your repositories.

There are multiple tactics possible to solve this:

- try uninstalling your 32-bit packages (as proposed by @MichaelHampton)
- investigate why you don't have an upgrade available for both versions (enabling/disabling repositories)
- tell `yum` to ignore some packages when updating...

Comment: I have the same version for 32 & 64 bit RPMs. IS there a way to tell yum to exclude ALL 32-bit packages?